# Can not run Elasticsearch on Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, curl, elasticsearch

I installed Elasticsearch on Linux Mint without any trouble.

Everything according this tutorial [Easy install for elasticsearch on Ubuntu 14.04](https://gist.github.com/Globegitter/662713f90d5af5b4269d).

All installation steps went well.
However, when I want to run easy check:

> curl http://localhost:9200

I got:

```
nazar@lelyak-desktop:~$ curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

PC reboot didn't help.

***How to solve this issue?***

Answer (score 1):

Follow official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html) instead of that linked gist - it refers to very old ES version.
Setup recent deb repository with:

```
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list
```

and install via apt.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the terminal and execute:

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```